# How do I make a link on my mobile site that causes Blackberry to make a call?

Tags: html, mobile, blackberry, phone-call

I have a mobile site with a "Call Us Now" link. It works for the iPhone, but how do I make it so that a call will be placed with a blackberry?

Comment: You can use [wtai](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11844/Feature_link_behaviour_438487_11.jsp) interface.

Answer (score 4):

The following `tel:` HTML link should work for both iPhone and BlackBerry:

```
<a href="tel:1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a>
```

See:

- [iOS Reference Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html)
- [BlackBerry Documentation](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11844/Feature_link_behaviour_438487_11.jsp)